# Better way between Bootstrap and Manual Design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a .net developer. Most of my time is spent in web application development using C#, asp.net, MVC, and Web Forms using BLL, DLL, service layer pattern design. But I don't understand bootstrap future. If I use bootstrap, should I know manual CSS, jQuery, and HTML design? I don't want to design a website manually, I would like to use Bootstrap, but I am confused about it.

- Is bootstrap perfect for all dynamic web applications?
- Will I face any critical problem using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is perfect for all. As usual, *it depends* on what your requirements are. However, with the information you've given it's impossible to say if you'll run into a critical problem.

One thing you will *not* find in Bootstrap but will likely need in any large application is support for grids and other controls like date pickers. You'll still need another lib for that. Fortunately, Bootstrap is sort of a de-facto standard so most control libs support bootstrap.

In the end, bootstrap only offers an easy way to give your application a consistent (good) look. It's a solid starting point but no where near a complete application development framework.

To use it properly, you still need to know HTML, CSS and js. There's no way around that if you're building web applications.

Answer (score 0):

BootStrap is good for dynamic web application. Even there are [bootstrap MVC helper](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/) available for MVC . With that said any web developer should know CSS , Jquery (atleast a decent dom manipulating capability) .

Comment: I want to use bootstrap to large web software like enterprise resource planning. To the job market will I introduce as a bad developer?

Comment: Well depends on the way you use bootstrap . Bootstrap is a framework which provides you with some good practices and there are many other framework which does the same . So adopting to a good practice is always good on the other hand do you want your website look just like other bootstrap application is a choice to be taken.